How to generate a label by using code and change its text by using trackBar c#
this code i use to generate a labels and trackBars in Panel but i want to change texte of the label by using TrackBar Value ?
i want to change text of the label to read trackBar value.
{
string mo = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM");
string ye = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy");
Dt = ge.get_all_vealuation(Convert.ToInt32(mo), Convert.ToInt32(ye));
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{ 
    TrackBar trackBar1 = new TrackBar();
    trackBar1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(12)))));
    trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(107, 27);
    trackBar1.Maximum = 15;
    trackBar1.Name = Dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    trackBar1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
    trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(217, 45);
    trackBar1.TabIndex = 3;
    trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(trackBar_Scroll1);
    // 
    // order
    // 
    Label lbl3 = new Label();
    lbl3.AutoSize = true;
    lbl3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    lbl3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    lbl3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 27);
    lbl3.Name = Dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    lbl3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 25);
    lbl3.TabIndex = 5;
    lbl3.Text = "0";
    //
    // panel3
    // 
    Panel pn = new Panel();
    pn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(12)))));
    pn.Controls.Add(trackBar1);
    pn.Controls.Add(lbl3);
    pn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 108);
    pn.Name = Dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    pn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(578, 167);
    pn.TabIndex = 2;
    pn.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(Mouse_Hover);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pn);

}
}
 void trackBar_Scroll1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     trackBar11 = (TrackBar)sender;
     label3.Text = trackBar11.Value.ToString();  
 }

enter image description here

How can I display the values of the track bars? Consider doing what the comment says and create a custom control.

Does the code compile? Does the Scroll event have a valid referenc to the Label?

this answer it's worked.
